# Icons all messed up for Office Documents

Tags: wine, icons, kde, playonlinux

I have installed MS Office on my Ubuntu box through PlayOnLinux and have got it very nicely integrated, except for one thing: my icons.

This all started after I **tried** to get MS' nice(r) icons into my Ubuntu instead of using the Unity icons.

Fast forward a few weeks...

I have installed KDE and can not change the icons, or for that matter, get rid of the MS icons.

What I have:
[image: What I have]

What happens when I go into file associations editor:
[image]

After I select my wanted icon (wanted one selected):
[image]

After I click OK on the icon chooser:
[image]

After I hit "Apply":
[image]

I have cleared my caches, done this after rebooting, looked for any files with conflicting names, but I just can't get it working how I want it to.

Comment: Okay. This magically started working for Word files, but Excel and PowerPoint files are still screwed up...